# ASP MVC 5 Email Confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

I am trying to enable the email confirmation on my MVC 5 app.

Here is my code as I keep get this error:

> [InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]

This is my register action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                First = model.First,
                Last = model.Last
            };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Default");

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                 string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                 var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                 await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return View("DisplayEmail");
                //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

and here is the email section

```
 public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        var emailManager = new EmailConfig(EmailConfig.EmailSystem, message.Destination, message.Subject, message.Body);
        return emailManager.Send();
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
    }
}
```

and here is where the email actually gets sent

```
 public Task Send()
    {
        foreach(var mail in this.mails)
        {
            this.client.SendMailAsync(mail);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

Comment: why does this all need to be async? Does it work if you remove all the async stuff? MVC will execute your controller action asynchronously anyway (i.e. it will allow other concurrent requests to execute), so I'm not sure why it's necessary. If you want the emails to send async without causing the request to wait, then you could consider using a separate service and have the MVC just put them into a queue for another service to process.

Comment: You can remove the `await SignInManager.SignInAsync` if you are sending the confirm email as you shouldn't allow signin until the email is confirmed. It looks like your *async* email sending is not waiting for completion.

Comment: I removed the Signin and it made no difference

Comment: Yes I will change to a queue however I am interested in what is causing the error not a work around to resolve the error

Comment: IMHO I'd say an email sending queue isn't a workaround but a more robust design. Plus it can be used from other apps and services that you create. But I agree it's a side issue. I'm afraid I can't help you with specific issue because I'd never have attempted to do it like that :-)

Comment: I have made it a queue and all is working correctly I am interested if anyone has a resolution please let me know